# Diverging Sound Horizon Cosmology

Tags: cosmology, textbook-erratum

So from my understanding the sound horizon equals

$$
r_s(z) = \frac{c}{3^{1/2}H_0}\int_z^{+\infty}{\rm d}z' \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(3\omega_b)/(4\omega_r))(1+z')^{-1}}} 
$$

However for all finite $z$ this integral diverges. Am I reading the formula in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.1613v1.pdf) paper wrong? (Equation 29). I omitted $E^{-1}(z)$ because according to that paper it is not a function of the integration variable. Can anyone help me understand how this formula can be useful if it diverges for all finite $z$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a problem in the paper you're citing. The sound horizon is (roughly) [defined](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1998ApJ...496..605E) as the distance that waves have propagated prior to redshift $z$

$$
r_s(z) = \int_z^{+\infty}{\rm d}z' \frac{c_s(z')}{H(z')} \tag{1}
$$

Where $c_s(z)$ is the time-dependent sound speed

$$ 
c_s(z) = \frac{c}{\sqrt{3(1 + R(z))}} \tag{2}
$$

and $R$ is the ratio of baryon to photon momentum density

$$
R(z) = \frac{3\rho_b(z)}{4\rho_\gamma(z)} = \frac{3\Omega_{b,0}(1 + z)^{3}}{4\Omega_{\gamma,0}(1+z)^{4}} = \frac{3\Omega_{b,0}}{4\Omega_{\gamma,0}}(1 + z)^{-1} \tag{3}
$$

Finally, the Hubble factor is usually written as

$$
\frac{H(z)}{H_0} = E(z) \tag{4}
$$

Putting everything together you get

$$
r_s(z) = \frac{c}{\sqrt{3}H_0}\int_{z}^{+\infty}{\rm d}z' \frac{E^{-1}(z')}{[1 + (3\Omega_{b,0}/4\Omega_{\gamma,0})(1 + z')^{-1}]^{1/2}}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I suspected something fishy was going on.